# Nifi handling failures and restarts without losing incoming data

Tags: apache-nifi, data-warehouse

I am looking for some suggestions and knowledge on streaming job failures and restarts.

I created a Nifi flow that captures changes in Source DB and push them to destination DB (a DWH)

the changes were captured using capturechangeMysql processor.. which runs 24/7 , so i call it similar to a streaming service.. During development whenever the job fails for what ever reasons, I stop the job, clear its state and fixes issues and reruns job again.

But when it goes live, whenever there is a failure of job, between the time i fix and rerun the job, all the changes that were happeneing to source were missed or lost.. imagine if the complex issue took a day to fix, all the data for 24 hours would be lost at destination.

I would like to know about different options on how to handle these situations and nullify data loss ?

I tried the option of "Retrieve All Records" in the CaptureChangeMySQL 1.18.0 processor. but it is filling up entire queues and taking forver to process latest records.

Can some please throw some light here..

Comment: Are you using GTID, you can check out this link https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/CaptureChangeMySQL-Error-when-restart-the-nifi-server-or-re/td-p/347063

Comment: Hey @DataWrangler, Thanks a ton for your response. although i previously tried GTID in nifi, I was never succesful. (because i have no idea that we have to enable it first in mysql :-) ) With your comment above i followed the process and its able to pick those transactions that were made on source DB when the job failed and before succesful restart.. more power to you DataWrangler /\

Comment: Happy that it helped, will add the comment as a answer so that you can mark the question as resolved or you can post the steps you did and you can accept your own answer. May the force be with you

Comment: @DataWrangler Just curious to ask if i need to use a message broker (like kafka) in this scenario ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @datawrangler, The config change that is needed, related to this question is to enable GTID. Then Nifi is able to track all the transactions even when the job is not running. So when it restarts it can process the transactions that were made in the source DB. In that way there wont be any data loss.

2 steps to follow:

1. enable GTID in the source mysql server as mentioned here: https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/CaptureChangeMySQL-Error-when-restart-the-nifi-server-or-re/td-p/347063
2. configure the Nifi CaptureChange mysql processor to use the GTID : 'use binlog GTID: true'